# using ifstatement in powerquery without adding an additional column

Tags: if-statement, powerquery

hi everyone im trying to use PQ for the first time..

let if column'security name'="future" then column'long/short'="Short' else "error" in
Please could you help?

I keep getting token eod expected errors.thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear (in terms of what your table currently looks like and what you want it to look like). I think the main problem is that:

```
let if column'security name'="future" then column'long/short'="Short' else "error" in
```

is not valid code, which is why you're getting an error.

I think one of the examples below should be what you want to do.

---

**Example 1: If you already have a `long/short` column in your table.**

[image: Example 1]

If you want the change an existing `long/short` column to either `Short` or `error` (based on the value in column `security name`), then in the query editor:

1. Go to: `Add Column` > `Conditional Column`
2. Fill out the fields as below and then press OK:

[image: Conditional column]

3. Then remove the old `long/short` column (right-click the `long/short` column header and click `Remove`)
4. Rename the newly added column (from step 2) to `long/short` (double-click the text in the column's header and it should let you edit the column name directly).

I realise your question's title says "without adding a new column", but I think this is how you'd do it in Power Query via the GUI only (as opposed to via the Advanced Editor).

---

**Example 2: If you don't have a `long/short` column in your table.**

1. Follow steps 1-2 (only) from the example above, but in step 2 name the column `long/short` instead of `tempColumn`.

---

If you find these approaches are a bit clunky, it can be done in one step with `Table.TransformRows`, but I couldn't find this functionality in the GUI (meaning there's no beginner friendly way to use it).